# How to get memory ( private working set ) of a process in powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, memory, memory-management, process

In task manager we can see memory ( private working set ).

My question is How to get memory ( private working set ) of a process in powershell? See image
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQInb.jpg)

Comment: Take a look at `Get-Process|Get-Member`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it is this:

```
(Get-Counter "\Process(*)\Working Set - Private").CounterSamples
```

**EDIT: Convert value to MB:**

The following takes the output of `Get-Counter` and sorts the processes alphabetically, then creates a table with the Working Set value converted to MB:

```
(Get-Counter "\Process(*)\Working Set - Private").CounterSamples |
    Sort-Object InstanceName |
        Format-Table InstanceName, @{Label="PrivateWorkingSet"; Expression={$_.CookedValue / 1MB}} -AutoSize
```

Comment: Thnx..thats what i wanted....one question though, how can i convert it in to Kb or Mb?

Comment: @RahulhAs, I edited my answer to show how to get a table with Working Set in MB.  Swap the 'MB' for 'KB' to show in Kilobytes.

Comment: Thanks. That will save my day in office

Comment: @RahulhAs, feel free to accept it as the answer :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why this not work please ?

```
get-process -Name iexplore | select name, @{Name="Private Working Set"; Expression = {(Get-Counter "\Process(*)\Working Set - Private").CounterSamples | Sort-Object InstanceName | Format-Table InstanceName, @{Label="PrivateWorkingSet"; Expression={$_.CookedValue / 1MB}} -AutoSize}}
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
get-process -Name iexplore | 
select name, @{Name = "Private Working Set"; Expression = { 
        $ProcessID = $_.ID; [math]::Round((gwmi Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfProc_Process | 
                ? {$_.IDprocess -eq $ProcessID }).WorkingSetPrivate / 1mb, 0)
    }
}
```