# How to get Memory (Private working set) per users in powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm trying to get the memory usage of process per user (like task manager), that info comes to Memory (Private working set) if we convert that values into MB we should get the memory usage, like in the users view in task manager...

Maybe i missing something, if someone know about this pls tell me.

And this is my script

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process | Sort-Object -Property privatememorysize -Descending | 
Select processname, @{Name="Mem Usage(MB)";Expression={[math]::round($_.privatememorysize/ 1mb,2)}},@{Name="UserID";Expression={$_.getowner().Domain+"\"+$_.getowner().user}} | fl *
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `WorkingSetSize` instead of `PrivateMemorySize`.

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process | Sort-Object -Property WorkingSetSize -Descending | 
Select processname, @{Name="Mem Usage(MB)";Expression={[math]::round($_.WorkingSetSize / 1mb,2)}},@{Name="UserID";Expression={$_.getowner().Domain+"\"+$_.getowner().user}} | FL
```

Comment: I need the values ​​in the column memory private working set, that's the value that we see in the users view in the task manager

if i use Workingsetsize the values what i've got doesn't match

Comment: I don't see any value that matches the __Memory(Private Working Set)__ in Task Manager exposed as a property of either `Get-WmiObject Win32_Process` or `Get-Process`.  However __Memory - Working Set__ can be added as a column to Task Manager (View -> Select Columns) and it matches exactly.  Would that work for your needs?

Comment: Here's a [SuperUser article](https://superuser.com/questions/802785/powershell-get-process-and-task-manager-discrepancy) about the discrepancy with some good linked info.

Comment: i know that the working set give me the exact value that i get, that it's not the value in task manager(Users View)... for example Notepad ++ process in script = 28144KB, this is if i use WS ..... Notepad ++ process in Task manager(Detail view, colum: Private working set)= 22016KB -> If i convert that to MB (20MB more o less) and that 20MB is what i need, but i dont know how to get that

Comment: [This article](https://powershell.org/forums/topic/get-process-working-set-vs-task-manager-memory/) mentions that the Task Manager 'isn't actually giving you truthful information for the job task you're trying to perform. And what Task Manager show you isn't just one value. It does some addition under the hood and shows you a composite.'
If you care about being close to the Task Manager Private Memory, you can try @TheMadTechnician's technique, or [this perf counter technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50735404/how-to-get-memory-private-working-set-of-a-process-in-powershell).

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the `Win32_Process` class doesn't have a property named 'privatememorysize'. <strike>Replacing that with 'privatepagecount' instead makes this work as expected.</strike>

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process | Sort-Object -Property privatepagecount -Descending | 
    Select processname, @{Name="Mem Usage(MB)";Expression={[math]::round($_.privatepagecount/ 1mb,2)}},@{Name="UserID";Expression={$_.getowner().Domain+"\"+$_.getowner().user}}
```

I see, that is not the same, so we have the issue here where the WMI object doesn't give private working set, and other methods that do include that don't have the user. So what we can do is use `Get-Process` to get each process and the private working set, and use `Get-WMIObject` to get the user associated with each object, and then match them up. Probably best to make a hashtable from one to reference, then use that to add the property to the other object. So, let's do that!

```
#Get WMI Process objects
$WMIProcs = Get-WmiObject Win32_Process
#Get Get-Process object
$GPProcs = Get-Process
#Convert Get-Process objects to a hashtable for easy lookup
$GPHT = @{}
$GPProcs | ForEach-Object {$GPHT.Add($_.ID.ToString(),$_)}
#Add PrivateWorkingSet and UserID to WMI objects
$WMIProcs|ForEach-Object{ 
    $_ | Add-Member "Mem Usage(MB)" $([math]::round($GPHT[$_.ProcessId.ToString()].PrivateMemorySize64/1mb,2))
    $_ | Add-Member "UserID" $($_.getowner().Domain+"\"+$_.getowner().user)
}
#Output to screen
$WMIProcs | Format-Table ProcessName, "Mem Usage(MB)", UserID
```

Comment: `PrivatePageCount` is the [number of memory pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.diagnostics.processmemoryusagereport.privatepagecount). Rounding it to get MB is probably not accurate.

Comment: that was to close, the result was.. Notepad process in script = 28144KB..... Notepad process in Task manager(Detail view, colum: Private working set)= 22016KB, the result that i need to get is the value in the Users View

Comment: there's not a way to get the value of that colum?

Comment: Ok, getting the value from that column is possible, just not trivial. I updated my answer to get you the data you want.